# Disable vim bindings in python ipdb

Tags: python, vim, macvim, iterm, ipdb

After installing [this](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles) dotfiles repo with vim, zsh, git plugins my ipdb has vim key bindings instead of normal bindings.

Navigation with arrows is quite broken and now it sometimes enters modes like VIM 
( typing / normal ).

I was advised to check ~/.inputrc, which sets those bindings for command line tools. I found only one line there:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

I tried removing it and restarting terminal, but it didn't help.

I use iTerm2 and MacVim.

I know that this dotfile repo is an individual one with its own configuration so it might be a bit different from normal vim configuration, however I still think vim applies here its magic same way it does elsewhere so maybe someone will be able to help me with that.

Comment: @falsetru Yep. If you read carefully I wrote about that.

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to modify/delete the `.editrc` file. [This](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/tree/master/vimify) directory within the dotfile repo seems to enable the functionality you're describing.

You can also try asking your question on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/issues) since this question is somewhat specific to it.